# How to use 8bit encoding in multipart MIME messages in SMTP?

Tags: email, smtp, mime

I have a question about how to use 8bit encoding in mulitpart MIME in SMTP.
Per [MIME Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME), we can specify value of "Content-Transfer-Encoding:" as 8bit.
For such condition, do we need to use 8bit MIME extension for SMTP?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can only use **Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit** with an SMTP server that supports the *8BITMIME* extension.

In [RFC 2045](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc2045) section 6.2, it says "Mail transport for unencoded 8bit data is defined in RFC 1652".

[RFC 1652](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc1652) (obsoleted by [RFC 6152](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc6152)) describes and defines the **8BITMIME** extension. While I don't see a specific sentence to quote to you, the entire document *assumes* that if you're sending 8bit data, that you're using the **8BITMIME** extension.

I haven't seen anything to the contrary.